# Reject single Job recommendations in the user activity tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, activity-tab

I'd really like a feature to just reject single recommendations for jobs I get. I like the recommended jobs section on my activity tab, but sometimes there are matches that just don't work at all. E.g. I got a recommendation that was titled `... [US only!]` so I wouldn't even be allowed to apply for it (of course another solutiuon would be to provide options for location restrictions even for remote jobs). Had this one up there for a few weeks, taking the space for potentially more interesting matches.

Maybe hovering over one of the jobs could display a small button, somehow along this lines (I'm not a designer, though):

[image]

I could imagine this feature beeing limited to a few times in a certian period of time, to prevent people from skipping through lots of jobs.

Comment: `I could imagine this feature beeing limited to a few times in a certian period of time, to prevent people from skipping through lots of jobs.` What's the problem with skipping lots of jobs in a short time? If I don't like one job doesn't mean I then should like the next. If I don't like it I also shouldn't be forced to see it just because SO can't tailor job ads to me that I do like.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder you could just use the `Jobs` tab as intended if you want to go through all the recommendations - but I agree, it wouldn't really be a big problem

Comment: We now have the ability to dismiss jobs... but it hasn't made it into this particular place. I'll try to make some time to work on it (since we have the heavy lifting in place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback.

We've discussed implementing a dismiss feature as you suggest, with the added benefit of using the dismissal as information to improve your job matches.  The feature has not yet been prioritized, unfortunately, so I have to mark this one [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now.

**Update**: This feature is live. You can dismiss single job recommendations anywhere you see them on site: the activity tab, developer story, Job Ads, job search, and job listings.

Comment: ok, thx for the feedback